# How do you get RabbitMQ to run on Snow Leopard 64-bit?

Tags: macos, erlang, 64-bit, rabbitmq

I installed Erlang R14B using the --enable-darwin-64bit option and set the bin directory in my PATH.  When I run rabbitmq-server script from the 2.1.1 release I receive the following message:

{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_plugin_activator,start,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

I am unable to decipher any useful information in the dump file.

Answer (score 1):

brew install rabbitmq

Seriously, checkout [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)

also, to make it run, you can also use

cd scripts/

```
./rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Comment: That would not have worked.  My problem was with the http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v2.1.1/rabbitmq-server-2.1.1.tar.gz that I downloaded and what Homebrew would have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "Source code and tools (tar.gz)" rabbitmq-server from the RabbitMQ site use the "Packaged for generic Unix systems" rabbitmq-server.